# How to sync feature branch with master branch

Tags: git

while working on my feature branch, I found that someone made changes to the master branch. The feature branch which I'm currently working on needs to sync with the master branch. Tried to use git rebase, but it doesn't work (expected to see some file conflicts).

There are many modifications to the current feature files. Do I need to git add and commit (but don't git push) these modifications before git rebase?

Comment: *There are many modifications to the current feature files. Do I need to git add and commit (but don't git push) these modifications before git rebase?* Generally, yes. Rebase has an "autostash" option (that will do a variant of this for you) but because it uses `git stash`, I don't recommend it myself. It's a good idea in general to make a lot of small commits anyway; you can use `git rebase -i` to organize them into more sensible, better commits later, as long as you haven't shared them with others yet.

Comment: Note that after committing, [Seyed Amir KhalifehSoltani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72710948/1256452) will work, but there's an easier way: commit as usual, then run `git fetch`, then run `git rebase origin/master`. You do not need a local `master` branch at all!

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the following steps:

- Run `git checkout master`
- Run `git pull --rebase origin master` [To Update branch with remote repo]
- Run `git checkout feature`
- Run `git rebase master`
- if you face conflicts then you need to solve those conflicts and run

  - `git add <file_name>/ git add .`
  - `git rebase --continue`
- continue second step until you solve conflicts(remeber rebase compare changes commit wise)

  - Then run `git rebase --skip` if needed
- After you successfullly aplied rebase you need to force push the changes

  - Run `git push --force-with-lease origin feature` (safer way of force push) OR `git push -f origin feature`

FOR REFERENCE: https://gitexplorer.com/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to rebase at all. In fact, it's my opinion that rebasing is something you should do if you fully understand the possible consequences (rebasing can rewrite logs which is not usually a good idea for auditing changes, merging does not).

You can simply `git fetch ; git pull origin master` to bring in their changes, then fix any merge conflicts caused by that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebase master:

```
git checkout master
git pull master
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
```

Your feature-branch commits will be ahead of last commit in master branch.